# how do i remove coredata from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

You know how you can Reset the coredata store on an iPhone simulator when you've changed your entity structure?

Do I need to perform a similar process when I've created a new version of my core data store that is different from what I last ran on my iPhone?  If so, how, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for convenience, until you code a way to remove the persistent store through your app, you can just delete the app off the phone. (Hold your finger on the home screen until icons get wiggly, then click the x on your app.) Then with your phone connected to your Mac, choose Product > Run in XCode and it will reinstall your app on the phone, but with empty data directories.

For deployment, of course, you need to come up with a way to do it without deleting the app, if you will ever change your data model after deployment (assume you will). Data migration is the best option, but if all else fails delete the persistent store file. It would be preferable to prompt for the user's approval before doing that. If they have important data they can decline and maybe get the old version of your app back to view the data and migrate it by hand, or they can wait until you release version 2.0.1 that fixes your data migration bug.

Comment: Thanks morningstar! I tried your first option for now. I loved when it warned me that my data store would be removed too. Just wanted I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the routine I use to reset my App content. It erases the store *and* any other file stored.

```
- (void) resetContent
{
    NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString * rootDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSURL *rootURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:rootDir isDirectory:YES];

    NSArray *content = [localFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:rootURL includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants error:NULL];

    for (NSURL *itemURL in content) {
        [localFileManager removeItemAtURL:itemURL error:NULL];      
    }

    [localFileManager release];
}
```

If you only want to erase the store, since you know its file name, you can refrain from enumerating the document directory content:

```
- (void) resetContent
{
    NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString * rootDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSURL *rootURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:rootDir isDirectory:YES];

    NSURL *storeURL = [rootURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myStore.sqlite"];
    [localFileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:NULL];     

    [localFileManager release];
}
```

But please note that in many cases, its better to migrate your store when you change your model, rather than to delete it.

Comment: But remember to remove "myStore.sqlite-shm" and "myStore.sqlite-wal" journal files as well (that are created in iOS 7 and later for journaling mode), because they take most of the space and after removal of Store they are useless.

Answer (score 1):

locate your app in `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2` (iOS Version may be different) and delete the `.sqlite` file

Comment: Hey iPortable, it looks like you provided the path to the simulator. I'm looking to remove the datastore on my phone. Thanks though.

Comment: oops sorry misunderstood the question. In the first part you asked for the simulator so I thought you mean the simulator database. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the path that is being sent to the persistentStoreCoordinator on setup, and remove that file.   Usually the approach I have taken is that I set up the store to auto migrate, and if that fails I delete the store and attempt one more time to create the persistentStoreCoordinator which will use the now empty path.

Don't forget you may need to repopulate anything stored in the old database.

Comment: Hi Kendall: Can you tell me: 1. how to set up the store to auto migrate 2. how i delete the store off my phone other than how chown provides above?

Comment: Just use NSFileManager to remove the file.  You can google lots of examples on how to tell the store to auto-migrate.