# Remove old Store and create a new in existing App update

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to remove old Stores's data on existing users devices. What is the best way?
["Here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367719/how-do-i-remove-coredata-from-iphone) it is suggested to simply remove the sqlite file. 
Is this the right way and create a new fresh Store with Different Name and location? or Shall i create a versioned model?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method on the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to safely and correctly remove the store from disk.  Removing the file directly has some risks associated with it.

The method is `-removePersistentStore:`.